# Raspberry pi3 + Raspbian - Python serial problema com o driver cp210x

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, serial, kernel

Olá, eu gostaria de se possível, ajuda/dicas sobre o seguinte problema:
Eu estou conectando meu dispositivo que utiliza o driver cp210x à minha raspberryPi3 que utiliza o sistema Raspbian, através da comunicação USB-Serial, mas quando eu tento:

> [dmesg]

Eu recebo essa informação sobre o driver:

"[  282.796114] cp210x 1-1.4:1.0: cp210x converter detected

[  282.796396] cp210x 1-1.4:1.0: failed to get vendor val 0x370b size 1: -32

[  282.796407] cp210x 1-1.4:1.0: querying part number failed"

Generic code example:
Código genérico para exemplo:

`import serial
 with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600,timeout=1) as ser:
    ser.write(b'&00R')
    ser.write(b'&15R')
    x = ser.read()
    s = ser.read(10)
    line = ser.readline()
    print (line)`

> print (line) = b''

Se eu tento lsmod, eu recebo: "1 cp210x"

Se eu tento lsusb, eu consigo ver: "Bus 001 Device 007: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light"

Se eu tento uname -r, recebo: 4.19.25-v7+

Se eu tento stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a, consigo ver que o baudrate é 9600

Se eu tento lsb_release -r, eu recebo 9.6

Eu sei que o meu dispositivo está funcionando normalmente, pois se eu conecto ele através da mesma comunicação USB-serial ao meu computador com windows e tento utilizar um software junto ao dispositivo, ele funciona normalmente, mas agora eu preciso realmente utilizar a comunicação com a Pi para receber os dados nela também.

Obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: Don't ask questions that are not in Portuguese, please.

Comment: Traduza a pergunta, você está no SOpt.

Comment: Não tinha percebido, já traduzi. Obrigado

Comment: Um problema comum que acontecia comigo ao usar esse conversor era que tinha que adicionar o usuário ao grupo `dialout` de um `ls -la /dev/ttyUSB*` e se for igual a `crw-rw---T 1 root dialout 188, /dev/ttyUSB0` add seu usuario ao grupo `sudo usermod -a -G $USER dialout`